# How to ban a commentator's IP address with Rules?

Tags: 7, rules, comments

When spammy comments appear on my website, I delete them and manually [add the commentator's IP address to the banned list](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/managing-users/ban-an-ip-address). However, it should be easier to Flag the comment with a new comment Flag *Spam* and then perform the previous actions automatically with a Rule.

The problem is that the Rules action *Block an IP address* cannot select the token [`[flagged-comment:hostname]`](https://www.drupal.org/node/390482#token-comment), which is perfectly accessible in other Rules actions. The reason for this problem is probably that the action *Block an IP address* only accepts values of the type *IP address*, as one can verify in the [original patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2219055-rules-block-ip-action.patch) for this feature. However, `[flagged-comment:hostname]` is not of this type (I think it is just a text). Moreover, storing the hostname in a variable and converting it into an IP address does not work either, because the latter is impossible.

Is there a fix for this?